# How to upload multiple images to one post in facebook via api

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So. I can't make this work and i can't find any solution about this.

Here is my code.

```
        $result1 = $facebook->batchApi('***********/feed', 'POST', array(
            'attached_files' => $facebook->attachFile($uploads[2]),
        ));
        $result2 = $facebook->batchApi('*********/feed', 'POST', array(
            'attached_files' => $facebook->attachFile($uploads[1]),
        ));
        $res = $facebook->processBatch(array(
            "access_token" => $user_profile['data'][0]['access_token'],
        ));
```

I'm using [facebook-batch-api](https://github.com/vlechemin/facebook-batch-api). It's just simple wrapper for batch requests.
Need make post like this https://www.facebook.com/centrMAN/posts/587573351326832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** post multiple images to a single feed. (Dosen't make any sense either)

The example link that you've mentioned in simply posting photos, not adding photos to a feed.

So, instead of `/feed`, simply use the `/photos` API to get the result.

Comment: I find some kind of suggestion. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#photos.
So i need to create users stories, then  i can publish multiple images in single post.

Comment: It seems that now you can https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads#publishing-a-multi-photo-story