# facebook feed response null

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am using below code to share fb feed

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  caption: 'An example caption',
}, function(response){ console.log(response); });
```

response is always null i could not figure out why , i think when share done it must output some response

ref link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5

Please guide if i am missing something

Comment: what for do you need to know a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a reliable callback if you authorized the user with the `publish_actions` permission. In that case, you will get the Post ID in the callback.

Else, there is no way to determine if a user shared something.

Keep in mind that you are not allowed to reward users in any way for sharing according to the platform policy: [How to upload multiple images to one post in facebook via api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395998/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-one-post-in-facebook-via-api)

Comment: how to authorize users is explained very well in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: but you really need to answer my question: what for do you need to know if the user shared something? that´s a very important question.

Comment: if user shared something will some offer

Comment: ok, that´s why i asked. because it´s not allowed to reward users in any way for sharing. and you will never get publish_actions approved in the login review for this, so: not allowed and not possible. you MUST read the platform policy before creating any app.

Comment: users need to share only because they really want to, because your app is cool. create an app that users WANT to share ;)

Comment: hey bro i want to share my wbesite link not app

Comment: it does not matter what you want to share, app or website - either way, you have to create an app for your website to use FB.ui ;)